# JSON array from jquery to PHP by ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i tried to pass JSON array from jquery to php by ajax
but i can't figure out to get specific object from the json in php

my code:

```
client side:
var items = [];

items.push({
        name: "Test1",
        ID: "34",
        price: "678"
});

items.push({
    name: "Test2",
    ID: "34",
    price: "678"
});

$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/SendObjects.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(items),
        success: function (data) {
            var suc = data;
            $('#body').append(suc);
        }
});
```

PHP:

```
$_POST = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $_POST
```

Thanks!

Comment: you dont need file get content,

Comment: And $_POST is an array so try `print_r($_POST);` as echo wont display an array

Comment: Actually putting it into `$_POST` while legal is a bad idea as that is loaded by PHP. I would use another variable name there

Answer (score 0):

Using data from JSON with PHP
First, to drill in that JSON is simply a string, we’re going to write JSON into a PHP string and apply it to a variable called **$data**.

```
$data = '{
    "name": "Aragorn",
    "race": "Human"
}';
```

Then we’ll use the json_decode() function to convert the JSON string into a PHP object.

```
$character = json_decode($data);
```

Now we can access it as a PHP object.

```
echo $character->name;
Here’s the whole file.

<?php

$data = '{
    "name": "Aragorn",
    "race": "Human"
}';

    $character = json_decode($data);
    echo $character->name;
Here is the output.
```

Aragorn

Answer (score -1):

`$_POST` is array, so  you can use `var_dump()`